# Showing activity indicator after a number of seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to show an activity indicator for my network request if its taking a long time to complete.

Is there a way I can start the indicator after a certain number of seconds have passed to allow a request to complete? I dont want it to flash up instantly as that makes for a choppy UI/UX on fast requests, but cant see the best way to present it on longer requests?

I was considering using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0, execute: {}
```

however this would cause the timer to display even if the request was completed within 3 seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DispatchWorkItem`:

```
fileprivate var indicatorTask: DispatchWorkItem?
```

to run it after those 3 seconds:

```
func prepareActivityIndicator() {
    indicatorTask?.cancel()
    indicatorTask = DispatchWorkItem {
        // show indicator
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: indicatorTask!)
}
```

Since you have a reference to `indicatorTask` you can cancel it anytime.

Comment: I suppose in your last line, instead of `indicatorTask.main` you wanted to write `DispatchQueue.main`, since you can only execute a `DispatchWorkItem` on a `DispatchQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use a `Timer` object. When the request completes, just call `myTimer.invalidate`

```
 let timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(showIndicator), userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
```